# Adding/Subtracting Whole numbers from Time

Tags: excel

I have tried every which way to format cells to subtract the result from time for instance the formula in the cell = 11(this is 11 minutes) I want to take that result minus 8:00:00 to give me 7:49:00 but it doesn't work the result is ####### no matter how big I make the cell. And if I format the cells with the formula to custom [m]:ss then the value changes.

Sample of the Worksheet:

[image]

I want `Y2 = X3-W3` in a time format.

Answer (score 1):

So, if A1=11

Then in some other cell, (B1 in this example):   =TIME(,A1,)

Then subtract from the cell with 8:00:00.  (If it's C1...:)

=C1-B1

That will give you the time you want.

Info:  The main thing is that you have to tell Excel that your cell with the "11" in it, is minutes.  By using the =TIME(,A1,) you will get the value of:  12:11 am.  (If you keep it in Date format.)  12:11 am could also be viewed as:   0 Hours, 11 minutes, 0 seconds.   And now that it knows, you should be able to subtract.

Comment: Or using the OP cells: `=X3-Time(,W3,)`.  Which is more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=TIME(HOUR(X3),MINUTE(X3)-W3,SECOND(X3))
```

The `#########` is because you have a negative time.  Becuase Excel reads time as decimals of 24 hours, 8:00:00 is .3333 and if you subtract 11 from that you get -10.6666 and date/time can not be negative.